# When must we create site pages through visual studio?

Tags: sitepages

Generally site pages are created through SP designer. But what are business requirement when we MUST create site pages through visual studio rather than designer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One requirement can be that client wants a Custom Site Template (like Team Site etc.) and the template will include few landing pages etc.

We can use [SPWebProvisioningProvider](https://thedotnetter.wordpress.com/2014/03/28/provisioning-provider-part1/) class to activate features, add lists, pages etc.

For provisioning pages on List Creation, you can use [ListAdded](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sharepoint.splisteventreceiver.listadded.aspx) event receiver as shown in [List Event Receiver in SharePoint 2010](http://sharepointaspirant.wordpress.com/2013/04/02/list-event-receiver-in-sharepoint-2010/)

For provisioning pages when a subsite is created, you can use [WebProvisioned](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sharepoint.spwebeventreceiver.webprovisioned(v=office.14).aspx) event receiver as shown in [WebProvisioned Event receiver - a Practical Example](http://stefan-stanev-sharepoint-blog.blogspot.com/2010/09/webprovisioned-event-receiver-practical.html)

Comment: this example is correct. any other example when we must create Site pages?

Comment: What exactly are you looking for? There can be 100's of examples :) or there can be none; answer depends on your requirements.

Comment: Please tell any 3 other requirement. I mean situation should demand we MUST create site pages through visual studio rather than designer. Thanks in advance

Comment: Think of any requirement which requires to create pages automatically.. Like let's say when a List of specific template is created, few pages should also be provisioned.. Or when a subsite is created, few pages should already be created etc.

Comment: Can you send link for specific coding for this?

Comment: have a look at updated answer

Comment: @Sunil you haven't accepted yet :).. Kindly accept (tick mark) to close the question